# number of type 'long' changes its value when printed in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, long-integer

I parse JSON data and there is book id , it is a big number:

> "Books":[{"ID":88401542,"Title":"Building and Testing with
>   Gradle","SubTitle":"Understanding Next-Generation
>   Builds","Description":"Build and test software written in Java and
>   many other languages with Gradle, the open source project automation
>   tool that's getting a lot of attention. This concise introduction
>   provides numerous code examples to help you explore Gradle, both as a
>   b
>   ..."},{"ID":2676913857...}

```
long book_id = 0 ;
try {
book_id = jsonBook.getInt(BOOK_ID);
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "book id: " + );
```

it prints me some stupid negative number:

> book id: -1814548740

what is the reason? can it be because I print it without casting? 
my log statement should be:

> Log.v("book id: " + new Long (book_id)) ;

or

> Log.v("book id: " + new Long (book_id.toString())) ;

or

> Log.v("book id: " + new String ( new Long(book_id))) ;

Comment: I suppose the one that you are getting from JSON is string so use Long.parseLong

Comment: Bookid is a long use `getLong`

Comment: @Jens, thanks i figured it out.. yes it works now! you can write answer - and i will accept it ))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Book_ID is an Long you should use `getLong` to get the value:

```
book_id = jsonBook.getLong(BOOK_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this value exceeds the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Better use `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger book_id = BigInteger(jsonBook.getText(BOOK_ID));
```

I'm not sure if `getText()` is correct, but the idea is to fetch the value as a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in that:

```
book_id = jsonBook.getInt(BOOK_ID);
```

If `getInt(BOOK_ID)` returns a number that overflow the `int` type, then you should not expect it to work correctly. (I guessed `int` because of the method name).

You can either check for your JSON API if it has a `getLong` method, either store as string, and use `Long.valueOf`, `Long.parseLong` and so on...

Comment: hey thanks, i changed it to getLong(book-id) and it works now... thanks!

Comment: Then you can accept my answer :) (and post your JSON API so that I can complete the answer)

Comment: hmm, i dont' know what you mean by json api, json api EXISTS AS ONE for json? i m writing client for website it-ebooks.info

Comment: Are you using Jackson https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson , gson https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You use `getInt()` to read a `long`. If the long value you're trying to read is large than an int then what you get is normal.